# Dynamically added attributes are not available as dot notation completion hints in IDE

Tags: python, attributes, ide, runtime, hint

I've created the following class and instance:

```
class _Colors:

    def __init__(self):
        [self.__setattr__(shade.capitalize() + color.capitalize(), shade + "-" + color) for shade in ['dark', 'light']
         for color in ['pink', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'teal', 'brown', 'orange', 'purple', 'warm-grey']]
        self.__setattr__('None', 'none')
        self.__setattr__('Null', 'null')


colors = _Colors()
```

Because the attributes are added at runtime they don't appear as completion hints when typing in my IDE, which in this case is PyCharm

Example:
[IDE completion hint example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsUAc.png)

I've seen other Python modules create attributes and methods at runtime that *do* show up as completion hints but I've never been able to figure out how they do it.

How can I tell an IDE about class attributes that are created at runtime before runtime?

So far, I've tried creating the color object as an array, as a dictionary and as a class, and none of them will provide completion hints as-writte when they are created dynamically at runtime.

I would like to begin typing the class instance name with a dot `i.e.: colors.` then have all the colors that are crated at runtime to be available as hints, such as `colors.DarkRed`